# Linking listview to sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

Here is what I am trying to do and would like some advice on the best methods to do it:

- have a database that contains a word, and the name of an image file associated with that word.
- the words from the database will be displayed in a listview
- when the word is selected, a new activity will start displaying the word and the image in an image view.

Would it be best to store the terms in an array and have the list view populate from this array and then pull from the database onitemclick? Or can the list view be populated with the terms from the database?

Will android be able to display the image if the name of the file is stored in the db?

Comment: If you have a small amount of entries, then it's much faster to load all the data in the memory, than querying the database all the time. However, if you have got a lots of entries, then it is wise, to keep your data in the database, and load and display only parts from it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve what you're looking for is to store the term and image path in the DB, then use the path to fetch the image from whatever location you have put it in.

Images *can* be stored in the DB, but the general consensus is that it is better to store the image outside the DB and a path to said image in the DB.

Your DB can then be as simple as three columns... "_id", "term" and "term_image".

You can do a simple query to fetch all the info at once (thus only querying the DB once).

Then use the cursor returned by that query to populate your list of terms, and `onListItemClick` to start a new activity to display the associated image using the path from the list that is in the same record as the term from the list.

Query to fetch data:

```
public Cursor fetchAllTerms() {
    return mDb.query(TERMS_TABLE, new String[] { "_id", "term", "term_img" }, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Using it in your list:

```
    mTermCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllTerms();
    getActivity().startManagingCursor(mTermCursor);

    String[] from = new String[] { YourDBClass.term };
    int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.Text1 };
    SimpleCursorAdapter ranks = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mRankCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(ranks);

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
     String imagePath = mTermCursor.getString(mTermCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("term");
     // code to start your new activity and put the image path into the bundle to be passed
}
```

Comment: Can you provide any more detail on the methods you describe such as using the simple query?